# Ajax GET request calling POST instead (ASP.NET MVC5)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created an ajax GET call to perform a search feature. But every time the search button is clicked, it is calling the POST instead (thereby returning null error for the model). I am not sure what I have done wrong. Care to give a hand please?

My controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /DataEntry/ChargeBack
    public ActionResult ChargeBack(string dwName, string searchTerm = null)
    {
        var model = createModel();

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_Suppliers", model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /DataEntry/ChargeBack
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ChargeBack(ChargeBackViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.someAction();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

My Main View:

```
    @model CorporateM10.Models.ChargeBackViewModel

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "get",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "SuppliersList"
            }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="search" name="searchTerm" class="form-control col-md-2" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search by Name" class="btn btn-info" />
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            @Html.Partial("_Suppliers", Model)

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

My Partial View:

```
@model CorporateM10.Models.ChargeBackViewModel

<div class="form-group" id="SuppliersList">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Suppliers)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Suppliers)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What makes you think it's doing a POST?

Comment: Change type="submit" by type="button" ?

Comment: @DavidG, it's trying calling the post method with the model, ChargeBackViewModel. I get the error that the model is null. If it were calling GET, there wouldn't be any such error.

Comment: @OuSs, thanks for the suggestion. I've tried changing it to 'button'. This time it is not calling post, but another error showed up: Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it. It is being caused by not including jquery.unobtrusive-ajax library. Once included, the Ajax action works as intended.